# Which similar/confusable airport names are furthest apart?

Tags: airports, factoids

Which similar (IATA) named airports are furthest apart, geographically? (bonus points if they're different countries/continents/separated by ocean/speak different languages)

By similar I mean either: a) change one letter (LHP-LHR), or b) switch two adjacent letters, or c) otherwise where one name might tend to be confused for another city (examples below).

Some examples:

- BEI is Beica, Ethiopia not Beijing, China (PEK)
- COP is not Copenhagen (CPH), but Cooperstown-Westville Airport, NY, US ; and neither is KPH (Pauloff Harbor Seaplane Base, Sanak Island, Alaska, US)
- JOH is Port Saint Johns, South Africa, not Johannesburg (JNB)
- SIN is Singapore not Las Vegas (LAS)
- SEN is London Southend Airport, UK not Senegal
- STP is St. Paul Downtown Airport (Holman Field), Minnesota, US not St Petersburg, Russia (LED) which is also not the other St Petersburg (PIE)
- SUN is ironically in Hailey, Idaho, US, not anywhere sunny. Equally ironically, DRK is Drake Bay, Costa Rica
- TOR is Torrington, Wyoming, US not Toronto, Canada (YYZ) or [the other nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_the_Greater_Toronto_Area)
- GAT is not London Gatwick (LGW) but Tallard Airport, Gap, France
- LHR (London Heathrow) - LHP (Lehu, Papua New Guinea)
- ROM (Rome) - ROP (Rota Island, Northern
  Mariana Islands)
- MAD (Madrid) - MAE (Madera Municipal Airport, California, US)
- Delta Municipal Airport (DTA) is in Utah, nowhere near Delta's hub of ATL
- At least USA (Concord, North Carolina, US) is in the USA. But CHN is in  Korea. Whereas KOR is in Papua New Guinea.

Serious motivations:

1. This is a thought of mine, ever since I had to rebook and jump on a flight to San Jose SJC in a hurry, I was not 100% familiar with US airport codes, my employer required us to make all bookings through a not-so-reliable internet-based travel agent and wondered as I woke up just before landing whether might have actually sent me to SJO Costa Rica (/SJE/...)
2. @nemirni below cites a newspaper report about two German tourists ending up in Rijeka,Croatia (RJK) instead of Reykjavik, Iceland(RYK) as intended due to wrong booking.
3. Several years ago, Hotwire and Orbitz used to sell some truly insane 36+hour international itineraries (through third and fourth countries) in response to legitimate inquiries like "SFO-LHR" or "SFO-DUB"; a flight which should typically take 14.5 hours (nonstop) or 18 hours (with one connection). I saw some bizarre routings through obscure minor Canadian and US airports (which could require Canadian visa); also some European countries.

Comment: I think LHR-LHP is good because of the casual potential for sabotaging luggage tags... (yes I know that's why there's a barcode...)

Comment: Why in the world should *SIN* be Las Vegas? I'd say *SIN* for *Singapore* is a very straightforward mapping.

Comment: Dontcha know Las Vegas is Sin City. If IATA auctioned names, would be interesting.

Comment: Ok, I see that's one of the nicknames listed in the [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas). I suspect that connection between the three letters "SIN" and the city of Las Vegas is rather obscure outside of the US, or at least outside of the English lingual sphere.

Comment: Las Vegas is not "BET" either, strangely that's up in western Alaska.

Comment: And the Google 767 would not want to land at XYE or XZA either, but in Mountain View. Except not Mountain View airport which is in Missouri (MNF) but at [Moffett Field (NUQ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moffett_Federal_Airfield)), which is a federal airbase.

Comment: If you count that kind of connections, we also need to wonder why the [Cologne/Bonn airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne_Bonn_Airport) is called *CGN* rather than *ELF*, which denotes an airport in Sudan. But I suspect there is no reasonably verifiable answer to your question, unless you restrict the scope to obvious lexicographical matches between IATA codes and official city names.

Comment: Now you've lost me: why should Cologne/Bonn airport be called ELF? Ah, Heinzelmännchen. That was gloriously oblique. Would you like a job at that online travel agent? You sound like manager material.

Comment: Another more verifiable example, for instance, would be the fact that [Kos airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kos_Island_International_Airport) is abbreivated *KGS*, whereas the IATA code *KOS* refers to [an airport in Cambodia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sihanoukville_International_Airport). Still, I think the examples in the question are sufficient now; you're not asking for a list (nor should you), you're asking for the pair that is furthest apart.

Comment: "Now you've lost me: why should Cologne/Bonn airport be called ELF?" - Read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elferrat) :) To Germans, it's a rather obvious connection, just like "sin" or "bet" may be an obvious reference to Las Vegas for Americans. I just listed it to support my claim that when including local nicknames, the possible answers are endless and hardly verifiable, unless we actually compile a list of all city nicknames from all languages and then find the pair of possibly misleading codes that are farthest apart.

Comment: That's true, but very geekily SQL is actually in San Carlos, California, local to the heart of the database industry. Whereas ORM is Sywell Aerodrome, Northampton / Peterborough, United Kingdom.

Comment: And nobody owns WIN. (Winnipeg is YWG)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not about a real issue someone faces and ventures too far in trivia territory.

Comment: @Relaxed: it is about a real issue. Read it again. I once had a serious possibility that my reservation to San Jose might have landed me in SJO. You don't think that's a real issue?

Comment: I remember a newspaper article from few years back telling a story about two german tourist ending up in Rijeka,Croatia (RJK) instead of Reykjavik, Iceland(RYK) as intended due to wrong booking.

Comment: @smci Yes, I noticed that but the whole discussion that ensued and the very broad rules you set make it way too arbitrary. Also, the wrong airport is the wrong airport, how does it matter which is the absolute farthest? In a way, airports close to each other afford many more opportunities for confusion, if you are about to book a ticket to Papua New Guinea, you will easily notice that the price and times are completely off.

Comment: @Relaxed: a) they're not very broad. Those codes/names are legitimately confusable. b) *"How does it matter which is the absolute farthest?"* because LGW/LHR can be fixed by taking a coach, but SJC/SJO or RJK/RYK cannot. LHR/LHP would be a huge error.

Comment: Or my friend who booked a Ryanair to fly into Frankfurt (HHN) on New Year's Eve for a 4-hour layover to a connection back to Japan to get him back to work from his Christmas holiday. Except that flight departed from FRA. Being as it was New Year's Eve he had to take a taxi ($$$).

Comment: @smci An actual travel problem (although still far fetched) would be “Which confusion should I be mindful of” or “Which airports on different continents/more then x0000 km from each other can be confused”. Absolute farthest is pure trivia.

Comment: @smci But that's making my point! HHN is Ryanair misleading passengers about the location of the airport and a genuine problem. It has nothing at all to do with somewhat similar IATA codes for airports on different continents.

Comment: I don't see this is much different from *“Which airports on different continents/more then 2000 km from each other can be confused”*? You might also remember that a few years ago, Hotwire and Orbitz used to sell some truly insane 36+hour international itineraries in response to legitimate inquiries like "SFO-LHR" or "SFO-DUB"; a flight which should typically take 14.5 hours (nonstop) or 18 hours (with one connection).

Comment: @smci I know that but that still doesn't make this a useful question. And it's more than the title that bothers me. Beyond that, close votes are there for a reason so that's what I will let stand for the moment. Maybe I'm wrong and your question will remain regardless. Maybe it will get closed and then it's up to you to improve it. That's the way it works.

Comment: @Relaxed: this question bothers you, on a site with the multiply-upvoted [Etiquette: Sex In Hotel Beds](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52651/etiquette-sex-in-hotel-beds) and [Is it permitted to ask questions of female sex workers in Thailand to be familiar with their real life as a tourist?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19564/is-it-permitted-to-ask-questions-of-female-sex-workers-in-thailand-to-be-familia) . Have I missed something? Will people ask next how they tickle Elmo in Thailand?

Comment: MAN/MHT. Codes aren't that similar, but they're both "Manchester Airport" and neither city is that famous among people likely to be wanting the other.

Comment: Not an IATA code thing, but several times travelers or their agents have confused the Cape Breton Island industrial town of  Sydney NS (Nova Scotia, Canada) with Sydney NSW (New South Wales, Australia) and actually [ended up there](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/nova-scotia/italian-tourists-end-up-in-wrong-sydney-1.975605).

Comment: Agree that this is too frivolous for travel.se, but puzzles.se would be a great place for it. But you should try to make the rules as objective as possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27671/discussion-on-question-by-smci-which-similar-confusable-airport-names-are-furthe).

Answer (score 1):

NAU : napuka island - NAV : Kapadokya (Turkey)

Nas Glenview - NBU
Cana Brava  - Brazil -NBV